# How do you upgrade to a smasher tank?

Tags: diep.io

I found this upgrade diagram, but it doesn't explain how you upgrade to the smasher tank?

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have just played a bit this game so sorry for the noob question but, what's a **smasher tank**?

Comment: @Alex the Smasher tank is the tank that is about at 7 o clock in the diagram above (it's the one that's a hexagon with a purple/dark blue background).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you level 30 yet? Apparently you need to be.

From [the Wiki](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Smasher):

> The Smasher is one of the five basic upgrade choices from the Tank. Unlike other Tank Upgrades, it becomes selectable at Level 30. It may further upgrade into the Landmine, the Auto Smasher or the Spike.

It's considered one of the basic upgrades because it would be the first upgrade you make if you chose to wait until level 30.  I'm assuming that the diagram above is tiered out to the corresponding levels you need to be to upgrade to that tank (meaning the Smasher tank is in the level 30 tier), but having never played the game, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Ohh yeah, that would make sense, I'm assuming the grey areas of the diagram represent skipping a level of tank upgrade, makes sense now, thanks bro

Comment: @JamesSmith that's exactly what I was thinking about the grey areas.